# IntelliJ IDEA : no option to extract to constant in Kotlin files

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA offers to [extract values to constants](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-constant.html).

The shortcut on my machine is `Cmd`+`Alt`+`C` : [image: shortcuts]

However, when I select a string in my Kotlin code and use the shortcut, nothing happens.

When I run `Refactor This`, the option does not even appear:

.[image: refactor this]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzMqm.png)

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2018.3.5 and Kotlin 1.3.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no question I suppose you are asking if there is such feature.

I have this feature in refactoring menu available in IDEA 2022.1.1.
Jetbrains probably add this improvement since 2018.3.5.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126365)

Comment: Confirmed on IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition). Thanks!